# Retrofit Help, always getting responseFailed

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have been trying to learn implementing Retrofit since past couple of days but I have been facing some issues. COuld someone pls help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://query.yahooapis.com")                                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        Details client = retrofit.create(Details.class);

        Call<ArrayList<Condition>> call = client.reposForUser();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Condition>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Condition>> call, Response<ArrayList<Condition>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Condition>> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.print(t.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public interface Details {


    @GET("/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22New%20Delhi%2CIndia%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    Call<ArrayList<Condition>> reposForUser();

}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
package hawkeyestudios.weatherretro;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Condition {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private String temp;
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "always failed"? Always "onFailure"?  Can you provide logcat for or the output of "System.out.print(t.getStackTrace().toString());" ?

Comment: Are you sure `Conditiont` fields are OK? Following the url I cant see code, date, temp, etc there.

Answer (score 0):

**I made call to your API,based upon those json, I have segment the object.This is your Response class which holds the entire json, if you could request for Response class, you could get your json**

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("query")
    @Expose
    private Query query;

    public Query getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

}
```

------------The Query class which holds the Result class------

```
public class Query {


    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private Results results;

    public Results getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}
```

--------The result class which holds the Channels class

```
public class Results {

    @SerializedName("channel")
    @Expose
    private Channel channel;

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

}
```

---This is the Channel class which holds the Item class

```
public class Channel {


    @SerializedName("item")
    @Expose
    private Item item;



    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

**----This is the Item class which holds your actual data Condition which is not array but single object based upon your json response ---**

```
public class Item {


    @SerializedName("condition")
    @Expose
    private Condition condition;



    public Condition getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(Condition condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }



}
```

-----Finally the Condition class

```
public class Condition {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private String temp;
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private String text;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

//So finally make some change

```
call<Response> call = client.reposForUser();
```